# "Unable to locate tools.jar" while the environment variables are correct

Tags: cordova, ant, environment-variables, java

I want to configure my PC (Windows 7) so to use phonegap 2.7.0 and create an android application so according this tutorial I m confirured the enviroment variables.

Below are the variables we need on a configuration like this as shown in command prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Adokis>echo %path%
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86
;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Win
dowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
; C:\Users\Adokis\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\platform-to
ols;C:\Users\Adokis\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\tools;C:\
Users\Adokis\Development\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17

C:\Users\Adokis>echo %JAVA_HOME%
c:\Programs Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17

C:\Users\Adokis>echo %ANT_HOME%
c:\Users\Adokis\Development\apache-ant-1.9.0

C:\Users\Adokis>
```

The problem is that when I use ant command an error "Unable to locate tools.jar" is shown

```
C:\Users\Adokis>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I double checked all the variables which are correct but I can't figure out why is looking tools.jar at Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar while the variable is configured at 
c:\Programs Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Download and install the Java JDK (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) instead of the JRE.

Once this is done you *may* need to change the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable. I'm not sure if the JDK installer does that for you.

The file tools.jar is not included in the JRE as it's only the "Runtime Environment" and not the "Development Kit".

Also, check the values of `CLASS_PATH` and `JAVA_LIB` as Ant may be using them instead of `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Check if you have the correct values for the `CLASS_PATH` and `JAVA_LIB` environment variables. Ant may be looking at them.

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. My mistake was I have included /bin folder for JAVA_HOME environment variable.